# Edit URL Link to Report Server within SSRS Subscription

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

I recently upgraded from SSRS Report Server 2008 to Power BI Report Server 2017. I have set up an alias URL link to get to the server as well.

When sending a report from the new server via an email Subscription, there is an option to send a link to the reportserver along with it. When using the new reportserver, the link does not use the reportserver alias to link to the server. It instead uses the machine name of the SSRS server itself.

Example:           http://machinename/reports/reportname
Instead of:        http://reportserveralias.example.com/reports/reportname

I did find microsft's link that describes a URLRoot properly in the rsreportserver.config file. Here is a link to Microsoft's website that describes the file's capabilities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportserver-config-configuration-file?view=sql-server-2017

I tried editing it, but to no avail. I also tried restarting the reporting service afterward and that did not work.
May anyone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You indeed have to configure the UrlRoot in the RSReportServer.config file, but it must not point to the Web Portal but to the Web Service. In most cases, the virtual directory is named "reportserver" (verify this in *Reporting Services Configuration Manager* under *Webservice URL*).

The configuration option in the RSReportServer.config file is found under

```
<Configuration>
    ...
    <Service>
        ...
```

and in your scenario it should look like this:

```
<UrlRoot>http://reportserveralias.example.com/reportserver</UrlRoot>
```

As an additional suggestion, bind the webservice and webportal URLs to an SSL certificate (issued for reportserveralias.example.com or *.example.com) and use `https` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much! I found that I actually had two aliases for my reportserver... When after I deleted the one I did not need, then it worked great! I also have plans to use https soon as well.

Comment: Very greatly appreciated. Nowhere in other documentation was I able to find that you have to use the "Report Service" url, that's what fixed it for me.

Comment: Trying to fix this same issue. It seems that no matter what I put into URLRoot, if it contains anything then the reporting web site throws a "Something went wrong" error.