# MHTML Links in SSRS report Subscription Do not work

Tags: reporting-services, subscription, mhtml

I'm hoping someone can help me with this question. I'm using SQL Server 2019, SSRS 2019, developing reports in Visual Studio 2019.

I've created SSRS subscriptions using the MHTML format so I can have show a report in the body of the email. The report is a dashboard with charts that link to sub reports. When the emails are sent recipients can hover over the charts and see the link path, and instructions telling them to select link to open report. However, selecting any of the links only opens SSRS home page.

I don't know why this is not working. Can anyone offer some advice?

Per Alan Schofield below Adding URL

```
http://sedona/Reports?%2FMIS%2FCopy%20of%20QuickTest&acctnbr=654321&rs%3AParameterLanguage=&rc%3AParameters=Collapsed
```

Comment: What do the links in the email look like, do they look correct?

Comment: @Alan Schofield- Thanks for replying. yes. They match the url for the sub report.

Comment: Yes. link matches url to sub report. I modeled the report from one in use by another developer, working from a different SSRS instance. The formatting of our MHTML links match. However, his links work, mine do not.

Comment: Maybe it's a permission issue (just guessing). If you copy the URL and paste in a browser, check it works for you then do the same with the end user, if it works for oyu and not for them them could just be a case of adding permissions to the sub/drill thru report to the user.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try. However, I should have mentioned the links don't work for anyone. To be more specific, in VS they work. When I deploy report, they work from report manager website, when report sent as email, they don't work.

Comment: I just tested the link as suggested, and it also brings me to report manager home page. Also, the specific report I'm working is uses default parameters so report data is relevant to the email recipient.

Comment: Edit your question and show the actual URL, it sounds like the URL might just be badly formed but without more info it's hard to say.

Comment: Sure!. Added to post and here

http://sedona/Reports?%2FMIS%2FCopy%20of%20QuickTest&acctnbr=654321&rs%3AParameterLanguage=&rc%3AParameters=Collapsed

Thank you again for your comments. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: The URL looks wrong. For example after report commands such as `rc`, `rs` etc, there should be a colon and parameters should just have the parameter name followed by an equals sign followed by the value. Take a look at this reference for more details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16 and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Alan, Thank you for your help. With additional help from a colleague, we found the URLRoot setting in rsconfig didn't match the web service url. we corrected that and the links are working now. Thank you again for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the root cause of tis problem was the URLRoot setting in rsconfig did not match the web service url. Changing the URLRoot setting resolved the linking problem. Alan Schofield, thankyou for your help and suggestions. Your comments put us on the right path to resolution.

If it helps anyone, I referenced the following about URLRoot

[Edit URL Link to Report Server within SSRS Subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320279/edit-url-link-to-report-server-within-ssrs-subscription)